# Creating a delay using TIMER0 module on PIC16F1939

Tags: microcontroller, pic, assembly

Suppose we are using an external  oscilaltor at 8 MHz and needed a voltage high for approximately  1 second at pin RA0. One instruction cycle takes  0.5 \$\mu s\$. I made a subroutine that takes 25 ms, with the prescaler set to \$\frac{1}{256}\$.

---

```
delay
clrf TMR0
L0
movf TMR0,w
xorlw d'195'
btfss STATUS, Z
goto L0
return
```

This subroutine( accounting for the call and return instructions that use up two cycles each) takes up 49924 cycles.

So, to create a one second delay, all I need to do is to call this routine 40 times.

```
   counter equ 0x21
   movlw d'40'
   movwf counter

   bsf LATA, 0
   bcf BSR, BSR1
   L1

   call delay
   decfsz counter
   goto L1

   bsf BSR, BSR1
   bcf LATA, 0
```

However, in MPLAB's logic analyzer I get some strange results, the RA0 pin doesn't even go to HIGH! 
I am self teaching on this subject, and if you know any good online articles on this subject I would be very happy to read them. Also how can we do this using the INTCON register?

[HERE](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001574C.pdf) is the datasheet of the pic I am using. The OPTION_ REG is on page 187, and the INTCON regsister is at page 90.

Comment: I think stack overflow is the better selection for this question.

Comment: @Decapod Why would it be?

Comment: Over there is more knowledge.

Comment: @Decapod Should I just copy the question or perhaps it will be moved by the moderators?

Comment: Copy over there and delete here. I do not know at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should read the MPASM user guide to find out about features which can make your code easier to write and follow. Use `cblock` or `res` to allocate variables, and `skpz` in place of `btfss STATUS, Z`. Wherever possible use `#define` to give  symbolic names to 'magic' numbers, and use the predefined symbols for hardware registers and bits (eg. `bsf LATA, RA0` instead of `bsf LATA, 0`). Put `radix dec` at the start so you don't have to explicitly specify decimal numbers. I also recommend adding a colon at the end of address labels so they can be easily identified. Give each label a descriptive name, indent opcodes, and comment everything!

> I get some strange results, the RA0 pin doesn't even go to HIGH!

This may be because you haven't set the port up properly. At Reset all I/O pins are set to input *and* (if capable) analog mode. Before using a pin for output you must clear the associated bit in the `TRIS` register.

The PIC16F1939 has a lot of registers - too many to be addressed linearly - so they are split into banks. TRISA is in Bank 1, so you must select Bank 1 before accessing it. The `BANKSEL` directive is provided to do this painlessly. So to make RA0 an output you would write:-

```
  BANKSEL TRISA
  BCF     TRISA,RA0   ; RA0 is output
  .
  .
  BANKSEL xxx         ; for next register not in same bank
```

You have `bsf BSR, BSR1` in a couple of places. Normally you should use `BANKSEL` or `MOVLB` to manipulate the Bank Select register. Your code would change to Bank 2 if it was previously set to Bank 0, but not if it was any other bank.